# OnVScroll() not being fired in a dialog menu?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have the following class declared like so in the `.hpp`:

```
class AFX_EXT_CLASS MyClass: public CDialog
{
    ....
};
```

I have added the scrolling message handler in the class definition:

```
afx_msg void OnVScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar);
//}}AFX_MSG
DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

I have added the map entry for the message handler in the source `.cpp` file:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP (MyClass, CDialog)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(MyClass)
    ON_WM_VSCROLL()
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

I have implemented the `OnVScroll` message handler in the source file:

```
void MyClass::OnVScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar) 
{
    int vscroll_inc;

    switch (nSBCode)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

I have set `SetScrollRange` and `SetScrollPos`, and I do see the scrollbar in the menu. However, `OnVScroll` never gets called. I can drag the scroll all I want, but it just pops back into its `0` position upon mouse release.

I have another class declared as `class YourClass: public CDialog { ... };`, and using the same code, scrolling works fine, and `OnVScroll` is called.

Any clues as to what extra steps I may need to do in `MyClass` to get scrolling to work?

Upon debugging, removing `ON_WM_VSCROLL()` from the message map in `YourClass` has the same behavior as `MyClass`, i.e. scrollbar is there, but `OnVScroll` is not fired, so I suspect it has something to do with the message map.

Or maybe it has to do with `AFX_EXT_CLASS`?..I'm not sure. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you avoiding [CScrollView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cscrollview-class) and [CFormView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cformview-class) on purpose, or were you unaware of them?

Comment: The `CDialog` class cannot be changed per requirements, which is why I'm not using `CScrollView` or `CFormView`.

Comment: I don't really understand your question about scrolling menus. Can't you visually show us the issue with screen shots too?

Comment: If your requirements force you to avoid the canonical solution, you need to fix your requirements. Regardless, if you want to implement a menu, use a [`CMenu`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmenu-class). Menus are special in that they aren't your average window. They are also special in that they support scrolling out-of-the-box.

Comment: _OnVScroll never gets called_ -- Did you set a breakpoint to confirm that? --  _I can drag the scroll all I want, but it just pops back into its 0 position upon mouse release._ -- This is the normal behaviour. A scrollbar doesn't remember its position on its own. You have to call `SetScrollPos` in response to `WM_VSCROLL`. Study [How to Scroll Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/scroll-text-in-scroll-bars) which has example code.

Comment: I am not familiar with `AFX_EXT_CLASS`. It seems to be dll related. Adding it to class declaration doesn't seem to cause any problem in stand alone solution. Maybe you have a dll related issue.